# Random character for passkey?

Tags: android

I am generating a random character for a passkey using following code:

```
int randomNumber;
Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
randomNumber = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(26) + 65;

if(passkey.length() != 20){
    while (passkey.length() != 20){
        passkey += (char)randomNumber; 
        randomNumber = randomNumber + 5;
    }
}
```

Further in the code sometimes I add 5 or 1 etc.

How do I make it so that the random character is numeric or alphanumeric not any punctuation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code

**Create RandomNumber without any special character**

```
private String generateRandomID(){

            final int ID_SIZE = 16;
            final int NUM_OF_CHARS = 62;
            StringBuffer id = new StringBuffer();
            long now = new Date().getTime();

            // Set the new Seed as current timestamp
            Random r = new Random(now);

            int index = 0;
            int x = 0;

            while(x < ID_SIZE){
                  index = r.nextInt(NUM_OF_CHARS);
                  System.out.println("Index="+ index);
                  if(index < 10){
                        id.append((char)(48 + index));
                  }
                  else if(10 <= index && index <36){
                        index = index - 10;
                        id.append((char)(65 + index));
                  }else{
                        index = index - 36;
                        id.append((char)(97 + index));
                  }
                  x++;
            }

            return id.toString();
      }
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 3):

Put the characters that you want to use in a string, and pick random positions in the string. That way you can also exclude characters that are easily confused, like `O` and `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a [table of ASCII characters](http://www.asciitable.com/). You'll see that digits correspond to the integers 48 - 57, uppercase letters correspond to the integers 65 - 90, and lowercase letters correspond to the letters 97 - 122 (note: all numbers are in base 10).

There's a couple of gaps between those ranges -- namely, 58 - 64 and 91 - 96. You need to change the calculation of `randomNumber` so that it falls between 48 and 122 while excluding these ranges.

---

[Guffa's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386706/random-character-for-passkey/6386804#6386804) seems more appropriate; I'd suggest going with that. I'll keep this answer here for completeness.